# Strange result of floating-point operation

Tags: vb.net, floating-point

Problems like this drive me crazy. Here's the relevant piece of code:

```
Dim RES As New Size(Math.Floor(Math.Round(mPageSize.Width - mMargins.Left - mMargins.Right - mLabelSize.Width, 4) / (mLabelSize.Width + mSpacing.Width) + 1),
                    Math.Floor((mPageSize.Height - mMargins.Top - mMargins.Bottom - mLabelSize.Height) / (mLabelSize.Height + mSpacing.Height)) + 1)
```

Values of the variables (all are of `Single` type):

```
mPageSize.Width = 8.5 
mMargins.Left = 0.18
mMargins.Right = 0.18
mLabelSize.Width = 4.0
mSpacing.Width = 0.14
```

For God-knows-what reason, `RES` evaluates to `{Width=1,Height=5}` instead of `{Width=2,Height=5}`. I have evaluated the expressions on the right-side individually and as a whole and they correctly evaluate to `{2,5}`, but `RES` would never get correct value. Wonder what am I missing here.

### EDIT

I have simplified the problem further. The following code will produce `2.0` if you QuickWatch the RHS, but the variable on the LHS will get 1.0 after you execute this line:

```
Dim X = Math.Floor(Math.Round(mPageSize.Width - mMargins.Left - mMargins.Right - mLabelSize.Width, 4) / (mLabelSize.Width + mSpacing.Width) + 1)
```

Time for MS to check it out?

### EDIT 2

More info. The following gives correct results:

```
Dim Temp = mPageSize.Width - mMargins.Left - mMargins.Right - mLabelSize.Width
Dim X = Math.Floor(Temp / CDec(mLabelSize.Width + mSpacing.Width)) + 1
```

Comment: What happens if you use Option Strict On to point out where you have type mismatches and use `CInt()` etc. to avoid them?

Comment: @AndrewMorton: `Option Strict On` doesn't do any good. I still get the same result.

Comment: If this is to calculate the number of labels which will fit on a page, I am not convinced your formula is correct anyway. `availableSpace = mPageSizeWidth - mMarginsLeft - mMarginsRight + mSpacingWidth` (taking into account the last label's RHS spacing across does not remove from the available space), `widthPerLabel = mLabelSizeWidth + mSpacingWidth`, then `nAcross = CInt(Math.Floor(availableSpace / widthPerLabel)`.

Comment: The formula is correct as far as I can see. If there are `N` labels across the width of the page, Spacing occurs `N - 1` number of times. What I do is to remove last label's width from available page width and then divide remaining width by `((N - 1) * (LabelWidth + Spacing))`. Finally I add 1 to the result to count for the last label. Do you see anything wrong with that?

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense now. I was going to say that if you convert the singles to doubles then it works as expected, but I see you found a suitable workaround already.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to rounding error: you're taking the floor of a value that is very close to 2, but is less than 2 (while the mathematical value is 2). You should do all your computations with integers, or take rounding errors into account before using operations like floor (not always possible if you want the true value).

EDIT: Since vb.net has a Decimal datatype, you can also use it instead of integers. It may help in some cases like here: the base conversions for 0.18 and 0.14 (not representable exactly in binary) are avoided and the additions and subtractions will be performed exactly here, so that the operands of the division will be computed exactly. Thus, if the result of the division is an integer, you'll get it exactly (instead of possibly a value just below, like what you got with binary). But make sure that your inputs are already in decimal.

Comment: Not convinced. If this were a rounding error, why would it display correctly in QuickWatch?

Comment: I don't know how QuickWatch is implemented internally (e.g. whether it uses the same precision and so on). In any case, your code is broken, as any small floating-point error will affect the result of Math.Floor.

Comment: If by the RHS you mean Math.Floor(...), then yes, there's an inconsistency in what MS produces. I suspect an optimization bug (unless such optimization is allowed by vb.net?). But I repeat that the first issue is in your code.

Comment: See my Edit 2 above. Might help us get somewhere with it.

Comment: It doesn't really help as one still doesn't know what occurs internally (only MS can know since their code is not open). With more tests, one can sometimes guess what really occurs and what are the causes, but this is not obvious and may take several days or weeks of research. I've edited my answer since in your particular case, you can use Decimal instead of integers (both are very similar here).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the following expression evaluates to a value just below 1:

```
Math.Round(mPageSize.Width - mMargins.Left - mMargins.Right - mLabelSize.Width, 4) / (mLabelSize.Width + mSpacing.Width)
    = 0.99999999985602739   (Double)
```

But what's the reason for that? The truth is that I don't know exactly. The MSDN does not offer enough information about the implementation of `/` but here's my guess:

`Math.Round` returns a `Double` with value `4.14`. The right-hand side of the division is a `Single`. So you're dividing a `Double` by a `Single`. This results in a `Double` (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25bswc76.aspx)). So far, so good. The MSDN states that all integral data types are widened to `Double` before the division. Although `Single` is not an integral data type, this is probably what happens. And here is the problem. The widening does not seem to be performed on the result of the addition, but on its operands.

If you write

```
Dim sum = (mLabelSize.Width + mSpacing.Width) 'will be 4.14 Single
Math.Round(mPageSize.Width - mMargins.Left - mMargins.Right - mLabelSize.Width, 4) / sum
    = 1   (Double)
```

Here `sum` is converted to double (resulting in `4.14`) and everything is fine. But, if we convert both operands to double, then the conversion of `0.14` introduces some floating point error:

```
Dim dblLabelSizeWidth As Double = mLabelSize.Width ' will be 4.0
Dim dblSpacing As Double = mSpacing.Width ' will be 0.14000000059604645
```

The sum is slightly bigger than `4.14`, resulting in a quotient slightly smaller than `1`.

So the reason is that the conversion to double is not performed on the division's operand, but on the operand's operands, which introduces floating point errors.

You could overcome this problem by adding a small `epsilon` to the quotient before rounding off. Alternatively you might consider using a more precise data type such as `Decimal`. But at some point, there will also be floating-point errors with `Decimal`.

Comment: Hmmm... and what about QuickWatch showing correct result?

Comment: It would be strange if MS used `Single`. Any reason? I'd rather thought that the problem would be related to extended precision like what you can see in [GCC bug 323](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=323) or to rearrangement of floating-point code by the compiler. The latter would explain the different result shown by QuickWatch.

Comment: See my Edit 2 above. Might help us get somewhere with it.

Comment: The `Decimal` type might be more precise, but this is not the reason why it will yield better results here (in binary, you'll get the same kind of problems whatever the precision). The main reason is that the inputs are in decimal (with few digits), and in decimal the first operations are done here exactly.

Comment: @dotNet: QuickWatch (for the RHS) is not aware that the expression will be converted to `Double` due to the LHS. Therefore, the conversion is left away, resulting in accurate results.

Comment: @NicoSchertler: The LHS in my code does not force any type. Whatever RHS evaluates to, the LHS variable will be of that type.

Comment: @dotNET I'm talking about the `/` operator. `LHS / RHS`.